# iOS black screen when bringing app to foreground after some time in background

Tags: ios, swift, background, foreground

I'm trying to remove all storyboards from our iOS app as they are a huge mess when working in a team with Git.

I'm now setting the initial ViewController in AppDelegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let launchViewController = LaunchView()
    window!.rootViewController = launchViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    [...]

    return true
}
```

LaunchView is a simple view controller responsible of routing the user to login or main screen depending if he/she is logged in.

Before this, LaunchView was set as initial in `Main.storyboard`.

I already removed these lines from `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

Everything is working fine, except when we leave the app in background for a couple hours without force-quitting it (I'm not sure how much time is needed to reproduce this) and then bring the app back to foreground, an all-black screen is shown, as if the root controller disappeared. And we have to kill the app and reopen it again in order to use it.

This is driving me crazy because it is really hard to reproduce, since if you leave the app in background only for a few minutes it works fine.
I'm suspecting it has something to do with the app suspended state, but I'm not really sure.

Do you know where the problem might be?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Maybe this has something to do with the problem:
On the LaunchView, I'm sending the user to the main screen (if he is logged in) with the following code:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

let rootVC = UIStoryboard.main.rootViewController
if let snapshot = appDelegate.window?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {

    rootVC.view.addSubview(snapshot);
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC

    UIView.transition(with: snapshot, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        snapshot.layer.opacity = 0;
    }, completion: { (status) in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
else {
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
}
```

Is it possible that iOS is removing rootViewController at some point?

Comment: This issue in simulator or device? Is it a universal application?

Comment: @user1376400 This occurs on a device, I didn't try it on the simulator. The app is for iPhone only

Comment: do you have LaunchScreen ?

Comment: @a.masri yes, it is storyboard named `Launch.storyboard`. This is selected as Launch Screen File (`UILaunchStoryboardName` key in Info.plist).

Comment: Any other storyboard in the app? I mean in info.plist

Comment: please share your code for appDidEnterBackground

Comment: @user1376400 Yes, a lot of them (12 I think). Also, I still have `Main.storyboard` as I have the main view controller in there and didn't refactor it yet.

Comment: have you tried this? definesPresentationContext = true in viewDidLoad()

Comment: @JulianSilvestri In `applicationDidEnterBackground` I'm posting an `NSNotification' to default notification center, and using it in a couple observers to stop some processes running in background threads. Nothing UI-related.

Comment: You have to add <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string> this in info plist

Comment: @JulianSilvestri no, I did not try `definesPresentationContext = true`, but I will and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @user1376400 I don't think so, because I'm not using `Main.storyboard` as the Main Interface, I'm only using it as a regular storyboard.

Comment: Share the code in AppDelegate

Comment: Without seeing what happens when app goes to background or returns from background, it feels like guessing in the dark. Could you share the AppDelegate code? If too much or too messy, focus on app going to background and app coming to foreground methods.

Comment: @user1376400 @AlexIoja-Yang sorry, but the AppDelegate is huge. The app state related methods I only do something in are `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Both methods are sending an NSNotification to the Default center to inform interested observers, and these observers don't execute any UI-related code. I don't think this part has nothing to do with the problem, because it is doing exactly the same than before (when the problem didn't exist)

Comment: please share the complete code over this link "https://justpaste.it/"  and share the link here.

Comment: @Babul sorry but this won't be possible. I don't own neither this code nor its rights. I can't share the whole code.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri setting `definesPresentationContext = true` on `viewDidLoad()` didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to the transition effect involving a snapshot when swaping the `window`'s `rootViewController`.

I removed the transition effect and simply changed the `rootViewController`. Now it's working fine!

In code, I changed this:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

let rootVC = UIStoryboard.main.rootViewController
if let snapshot = appDelegate.window?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {

    rootVC.view.addSubview(snapshot);
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC

    UIView.transition(with: snapshot, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        snapshot.layer.opacity = 0;
    }, completion: { (status) in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
else {
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
}
```

To this:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
let rootVC = UIStoryboard.main.rootViewController
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
```

Thank you all for your help! I hope this answer is useful to somebody else.

Comment: You should not be changing the root view controller at all.

Comment: @matt I'm changing it to avoid stacking all the other view controllers to my `LaunchViewController`. What should I do instead?

Comment: Have one eternal root view controller that is just a parent view controller and change its child.

Comment: @matt Why? Is there any documentation or guidelines that says is a bad practice to change the rootViewController?

Comment: Well one obvious thing is that you could then have your transition that you just had to eliminate. Thus you would solve the problem the right way.

Comment: @matt Ok, but I don't think that deserves a downvote. I accept that as a suggestion, although I think it makes no sense keeping that VC (which won't be used or seen anymore) in the stack.

Comment: On the contrary an unseen master parent view controller is a correct and standard technique straight from Apple Inc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144523/swap-rootviewcontroller-with-animation/41144993#41144993