# Navigate from UIViewController to UITabBarController make double NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I want to navigate from the login screen to `UITabBarController`.
I use this Line to navigate --> `navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarVC, animated: true)`

When navigate show me two `NavigationBar`.

I want to solve this problem.

[image: preview]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144523/swap-rootviewcontroller-with-animation.  Presently you are pushing a new view controller onto the navigation stack of the Login VC, you really need to replace the root VC of your app with the `UITabBarController`

Comment: my root VC is Login Screen I want when click login button go to tab bar but the problem is navigation bar doublicated

Comment: I understand your question, the nav bar is duplicated because you're pushing a new view controller that also contains navigation controllers.  You should try the suggestion of switching root view controller...or better yet have the tab controller as your root view controller, then present the Login view controller modally on top as needed.  Then you'd only need to dismiss the Login VC after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of `UITabBarController` for your `tabBarVC`,
Add these lines:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```